# Visual C++ 2012 Express compiled application does not work on Windows XP?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012, windows-xp

I have the following C++ program which I am compiling with static linking (Multi-threaded (/MT)):

```
int main()
{
    return 0;
}
```

I tried to run it on Windows XP (using Virtual Box), but it is telling me that it is not a valid win32 application!!

Answer (score 1):

take a look at this:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vcblog/archive/2012/10/08/windows-xp-targeting-with-c-in-visual-studio-2012.aspx

you should install vs2012 update 1. and change your toolset to xp.

Comment: Can I just use Visual C++ 2013 Express?

Comment: well I'm not sure. but I think yes. Edit: according to this: https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/products/visual-studio-2013-compatibility-vs.aspx yes

Comment: Wrong link, that's the retail edition.  The point of Express is to keep the download small and express, the *extra* SDK that's required to target XP is not small.

Comment: This page is not for retail edition. It's for all versions. And I cannot find anything on the page which tells that you cannot export for XP using express edition.